# Do specific task for some lines, copy all other lines

Tags: awk

I have set of specific lines in file where I would like to do some changes, and I want to just coppy all other lines. I imagine code should look something like this

```
awk -v imin=5 -v imax=10 -v shift=5.54545 '{
(NR==5){ print $1+5,$2; }
(NR==7){ print $1+shift,$2; }
((NR>imin)&&(NR<imax)){ print $1,$2,$3+shift; }
(NR == EVERY_OTHER_LINE){ print $0; }
}' input_data.dat
```

But I don't know how to do this `(NR == EVERY_OTHER_LINE)`, meaning `every line except the ones handled above`.

Best what I found is here, but it is not really what I want.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563455/awk-print-all-remaining-lines

Comment: What is `shift` in your code? Does `EVERY_OTHER_LINE` mean `every odd numbered line` or `every even numbered line` or `every line except the ones handled above` or something else? Should the `NR>imin...` code also get hit when either of the lines above it get hit or not? [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to clarify your requirements and so we have something we can test a potential solution against. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton, OK, I modified it according to your suggestions, sorry, I was writing it in haste

Comment: You still don't show what `shift` is, nor do you include sample input/output. Don't write questions in haste if that makes you not provide all necessary information because that makes those of us trying to help you take longer than necessary - it costs us time instead of costing you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow the following approach:

```
(NR==5){ print $1+5,$2; next }
(NR==7){ print $1+shift,$2; next }
((NR>imin) && (NR<imax)){ print $1,$2,$3+shift; next}
1;
```

We introduce the `next` command to avoid that any *special* lines have a secondary `print` statement

This is, however, a bit convoluted, so the following method for this particular case might be better:

```
{line=$0}
(NR==5) { line=$1+5 OFS $2 }
(NR==7) { line=$1+shift OFS $2 }
((NR>imin)&&(NR<imax)){ line = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3+shift }
{print line}
```

Ofcourse, if record 5 and 7 only have 2 fields and the records between `imin` and `imax` with `imin>7` have 3 fields, then it is even easier:

```
(NR==5){ $1+=5     }
(NR==7){ $1+=shift }
(NR>imin)&&(NR<imax){ $3+=shift }
1
```